# hidden-sm-down on Bootstrap4 not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my images be above my text on m+ devices, and below the text on sm- devices. I'm using Bootstrap4, and to my knowledge following all the tutorials given from Bootstrap - yet it's not hiding my images.   Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="hidden-sm-down">
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="img-fluid" src="img/finding.svg" onerror="this.src='img/finding.png';this.onerror=null;" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<h5 class="heading">Get SMS notifications for new dates</h5>
<p class="sell">
This is where the text would go.
</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden-md-up">
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="img-fluid" src="img/finding.svg" onerror="this.src='img/finding.png';this.onerror=null;" alt="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the classes `hidden-sm-down` and `hidden-sm-up` don't exist in Bootstrap 4 Beta 3 anymore.

Instead of `hidden-sm-up` use `d-sm-none` etc.

Complete list here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: Thank you very much. I swear I was reading the most up to date version, obviously not!

Comment: Why would they remove those classes? They are simpler than combingi things like this ugly `.d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none`